Measuring disk usage in Linux for a file
I want to measure number of bytes needed when storing some information in file in Linux. I came to know character set is used to decide how many bytes will be used when storing information in a file. I tried the below steps to see bytes used but I can't understand why my file size gets doubled each time.

touch 1 - create a file with name 1

[root@pgsql1 iotest]# touch 1

character set and file encoding:
[root@pgsql1 iotest]# file -bi 1
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
    
[root@pgsql1 iotest]# enca -L none 1
7bit ASCII characters
    
[root@pgsql1 iotest]# echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8


stat 1 - output below

[root@pgsql1 iotest]# stat 1
  File: ‘1’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 831h/2097d      Inode: 12          Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2024-09-29 19:18:55.257153854 +0530
Modify: 2024-09-29 19:18:55.257153854 +0530
Change: 2024-09-29 19:18:55.257153854 +0530
 Birth: -
[root@pgsql1 iotest]#


echo "1" > 1

[root@pgsql1 iotest]# echo "1" > 1


stat 1 - output below

[root@pgsql1 iotest]# stat 1
  File: ‘1’
  Size: 2               Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 831h/2097d      Inode: 12          Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2024-09-29 19:18:55.257153854 +0530
Modify: 2024-09-29 19:20:02.806425277 +0530
Change: 2024-09-29 19:20:02.806425277 +0530
 Birth: -


echo "1" >> 1

[root@pgsql1 iotest]# echo "1" >> 1


stat 1

[root@pgsql1 iotest]# stat 1
  File: ‘1’
  Size: 4               Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 831h/2097d      Inode: 12          Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2024-09-29 19:18:55.257153854 +0530
Modify: 2024-09-29 19:21:03.907575276 +0530
Change: 2024-09-29 19:21:03.907575276 +0530
 Birth: -

But as per https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#:~:text=An%20on-the-fly%20UTF-8%20byte%20counter , I can see for "1" it shows 1 byte in size. But in stat out the file size is getting doubled each time, please some one explain how the storage allocation happens.

Hexdump the file and look

echo adds a trailing newline ... unless you use the -n option; see man echo.

Thanks to both of you for giving the information.

character set is used to decide how many bytes will be used when storing information in a file files store bytes. Character set is needed to convert from bytes to characters. Not all files store characters.

Note that file length is not equivalent to disk usage. The space on disk required by the file is usually a multiple of the disk sector size.


measure number of bytes needed when storing some information in file

Use wc to get the number of bytes stored in a file.
*This is not exactly equal to the "number of bytes needed", as the filesystem needs to store the file name and file access/change/modify timestamps, access permissions, uid and gid, and extected ACL, and many other relevant information in file inode. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode .
*Additionally, this might not be equal to the "number of bytes needed" to represent the bytes in the file on the actual disc, as with for example two discs in mirroring/RAID 1 you would need double the amount of bytes to store the file, and for example on a filesystem with compresion the bytes are compressed and then stored in the disc.

why my file size gets doubled each time.

echo "1" writes 1 and a newline character. That's two characters, that's two bytes.

Specifically, wc -c to count bytes.  Or wc -m to count characters, according to your LC_CTYPE.
